# PHP round different results

Tags: php, rounding

Hi i got some problem with rounding. For ex.:

```
$x = 100;
$y = 4.2030;

$result = round($x / $y, 2);
```

$result will be 23.79

but now

```
  $result2 = round(23.79 * 4.2030, 2);
```

$result2 will be 99.99 , so it's incorrect. should be 100 ($result2 equal $X)

how to slove it ?

Comment: Obviously, you loose precision when rounding a number.
round($x / y) != $x / $y

Comment: Why should this be 100... 23.79*4.2030 = 99.98937 rounding to 2 digits after the decimal place should and does give you 99.99

Comment: `23.79 * 4.2030 = 99.989370` if you're going to need an *exact* value for a further calculation the you should be storing the *un*-rounded value and only round it for display.

Comment: @jasneinfo, what means "rounding"? find out that, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: yeap, but need $result2 equal 100 . another way looking for a solution  to maximum round near 100 but not higher

Comment: Round(x,2) + 0.005, usually

Comment: Ooops! Round x +.0.005,2)

Answer (score 1):

Your round precision is two decimal places. If you are trying to get whole numbers you need to omit the precision argument:

```
$result2 = round(23.79 * 4.2030);
```

**NOTE: the lower the precision argument, the more inaccurate your result will be from the actual results.**

You can also use [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) and [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) if you are looking to round in a specific direction (`ceil()` will round up, `floor()` will round down).